# Apache PDF box pdf page to png image operation seems to not close the stream i.e. end the write operation

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

I am using the Apache PDF box library to convert a PDF page to PNG image format.

I have used both the ImageWriter and PDFImageWriter to write the "BufferedImage" object to a file in png format.

The BufferedImage object is created from the "convertToImage" method available from the pdf document object.

When the image is created and the image writer and document objects are closed, the execution does not stop and it looks like soem stream or background thread is still running.

I tried all this using a single main function in Java so that I know that the only operation running is the conversion code from pdf page to an image file.

I tried setting the image writer and document objects to null after closing/disposing the objects but I have had no success in this regard.

What I am missing? Please advise with some sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Subbu

Comment: Please post the code that you are using.

Comment: And mention also the version of PDFBox that you are using. The current version is 1.8.7.

Comment: Here is the code (sorry about the formatting) :  document2 = PDDocument.load(filename2+".pdf");
          List<PDPage> list = document2.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
          PDPage page = list.get(0);
          BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 200);
          page.clear();
          page=null;
          File outputfile = new File(filename2+".png");
          System.out.println("Image Created -> "+ outputfile.getName());
          ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
    image.flush();
      document2.close();

Comment: In my code snippet above, the problem happens when I create the BufferedImage object against the PDF page object. If I were to create a blank BufferedImage object, the image.flush() and document2.close() operations close out the streams and complete what is needed. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Also, I am using the latest Apache pdf box libraries - version 1.8.7.